# List down all custom webparts available under SharePoint Site using powershell

Tags: web-part

I have deployed webparts to some SharePoint site say "http://SiteCollection:6413/SiteName/". Now I want to know all the available Webpart which are addable to any page (whether are those already added to any page or not).

**Why do I want to know this?**
 
When I deploy the solution to QA Environment I am not able to find either web parts or Group under which those kept. But the page is working fine.
Once I deleted webpart from the page and wanted to add back I am not able to find the same on site.

Someone can correct me if they understand the issue and I am not able to explain it properly. Please help by tagging appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse below script according to your requirement.

```
######################### this method will return the WebParts in the Web Application and the Page Information



function GetWebParts()
 {
     Write-Host "Entered GetWebParts Method" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
     Add-Content "$ProgressFile" "Entered GetWebParts Method"
     $script:Progress = "4:Entered"

 # Get Web Application
 $WebApplication = Get-SPWebApplication $Config.Configuration.WebApplication.URL

 # Assign the XML Output File Paths
 $WebParts_XML_Path = $scriptBase + "\Reports-$LogTime\WebParts.xml"

 # Create the XML File Tags

 $xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($WebParts_XML_Path,$Null)
 $xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
 $xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
 $XmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
 $xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
 $xmlWriter.WriteComment('WebParts List On the WebApplication ' + $WebApplication.DisplayName)
 $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('WebApplication')
 $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
 $xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
 $xmlWriter.Flush()
 $xmlWriter.Close()

 # Get the site Collections Object 
 $SiteCollections =  $WebApplication | Get-SPSite -Limit All

 # write the output on XML File
 $xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $WebParts_XML_Path);
 $siteCollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("SiteCollections")
 $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//WebApplication").AppendChild($siteCollectionNode)
 $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

 # Iterate through the SiteCollections
 foreach($SiteCollection in $SiteCollections)
 {
     $siteCollectionName = $SiteCollection | select @{label = "Title";Ex = {$_.rootweb.Title}} 

     # write the output on XML File
     $xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $WebParts_XML_Path);
     $siteCollectionNode = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("SiteCollection")
     $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//WebApplication/SiteCollections").AppendChild($siteCollectionNode)
     $siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("Name", $siteCollectionName.Title)
     $siteCollectionNode.SetAttribute("Url", $SiteCollection.Url)

     $subSitesNode = $siteCollectionNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("SubSites"));
     $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

     # Get All SubWebs
     $Webs = Get-SPWeb -site $SiteCollection -Limit All 

     # Iterate through the SubWebs
     foreach($Web in $Webs)
     {
         # write the output on XML File
         $subSiteNameNode = $subSitesNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("SubSite"));
         $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("Name", $Web.Title)
         $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("Url", $Web.Url)
         $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("WebID", $Web.Id)
         $parentWebTitle = ""

         if($Web.ParentWebID -ne "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
         {
             $parentWeb = $SiteCollection.OpenWeb($Web.ParentWebID)
             $parentWebTitle = $parentWeb.Title

         }
         else
         {
             $parentWebTitle = "RootWeb"
         }    
         $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("ParentWebName", $parentWebTitle)
         $subSiteNameNode.SetAttribute("ParentWebID", $Web.ParentWebID)


         $webPartsNode = $subSiteNameNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("WebParts"));

         $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

         # Check For Publishing Site
         if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($Web))  # If the Current Web is Publishing Web, then proceed
         {
             # Get the Publishing Web Object
             $pWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Web)

             # Get the Pages Doc Library
             $pages = $pWeb.PagesList

             # Iterate through all the Pages  
             foreach ($item in $pages.Items) 
             {
                 $fileUrl = $Web.Url + "/" + $item.File.Url

                 # Get the webPartManager Object
                 $manager = $item.file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

                 # Get the WebParts
                 $wps = $manager.webparts
                 $wps | select-object @{Expression={$WebApplication.DisplayName};Label="WebApplication"},@{Expression={$siteCollectionName.Title};Label="SiteCollection"}, @{Expression={$Web.Title};Label="SubSite"},@{Expression={$item.File.Name};Label="Page Name"},@{Expression={$fileUrl};Label="Page URL"}, DisplayTitle, ID, IsVisible, @{Expression={$_.GetType().ToString()};Label="Type"}

                 # Iterate through the WebParts
                 foreach($wp in $wps)
                 {
                     # write the output on XML File

                     $webPartNodeNode = $webPartsNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("WebPart"));
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Name", $wp.DisplayTitle)
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("ID", $wp.ID)
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Visible", $wp.IsVisible)
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Type", $wp.GetType())
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("PageName", $item.File.Name)
                     $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("FileURL", $fileUrl)
                     $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

                 }
             }            
         }
         else # If the Current Web is not a Publishing Web
         {
             $pages = $null
             # Get the Site Pages Doc Lib
             $pages = $Web.Lists["Site Pages"]

             if ($pages) 
             {
                 # Iterate through all the Pages
                 foreach ($item in $pages.Items) 
                 {
                     $fileUrl = $Web.Url + "/" + $item.File.Url

                     # Get the WebPart Manager Object
                     $manager = $item.file.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.Webparts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

                     # Get All the WebParts
                     $wps = $manager.webparts
                     $wps | select-object @{Expression={$WebApplication.DisplayName};Label="WebApplication"},@{Expression={$siteCollectionName.Title};Label="SiteCollection"}, @{Expression={$Web.Title};Label="SubSite"},@{Expression={$item.File.Name};Label="PageName"},@{Expression={$fileUrl};Label="Page URL"}, DisplayTitle, ID, IsVisible, @{Expression={$_.GetType().ToString()};Label="Type"}

                     # iterate through the WebParts                                                
                     foreach($wp in $wps)
                     {
                         # write the output on XML File

                         $webPartNodeNode = $webPartsNode.AppendChild($xmlDoc.CreateElement("WebPart"));
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Name", $wp.DisplayTitle)
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("ID", $wp.ID)
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Visible", $wp.IsVisible)
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("Type", $wp.GetType())
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("PageName", $item.File.Name)
                         $webPartNodeNode.SetAttribute("FileURL", $fileUrl)
                         $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

                     }
                 }                
             }
             else 
             {
                 Write-Host "    Site Pages library not found." -ForegroundColor Red                
             }            
         }
     }
 }    
 # write the output on XML File
 $xmlDoc.Save($WebParts_XML_Path)

 Write-Host "Completed GetWebParts Method" -ForegroundColor Yellow 
 Add-Content "$ProgressFile" "Completed GetWebParts Method"
 $script:Progress = "4:Success"
 }



 ########### End of Method #################
```

[Ref1](http://sharepointpals.com/post/Get-the-List-of-WebParts-in-a-WebApplication-SharePoint-PowerShell)
[Ref2](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/07/listing-all-web-parts-in-a-site-collection-with-powershell.html)